# What is the purpose of resistance & capacitance in parallel to Load ( refer ckt )

Tags: led, capacitor, resistors, filter, decoupling-capacitor

What is the purpose of resistance & capacitance in parallel to Load ( refer ckt ) ?

As per my understanding these capacitor & resistor is for filtration[image] purpose ( kindly clarify the same) .[image]

Values of C1 is 2.2uF/50V/open mode
Value of C2 is 0.1uf /50V/ Open mode
Value of R19 is 10K .

Comment: What are the values of C1, C2, and R19?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Your image is very low res and hard to read. The site has a built in schematic editor. Could you use that to redraw the schematic's most important features more neatly?

Comment: Values of C1 is 2.2uF/50V/open mode Value of C2 is 0.1uf /50V/ Open mode Value of R19 is 10K .

Comment: Unless there are other considerations which are not shown in the diagram, they don't serve much of any purpose. The LEDs do not switch by themselves. LEDs are tolerant of power ripple. I think they are there because people are accustom to putting in bypass caps. With the bypass caps, it seems prudent to have a resistor to discharge them.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the LED's with have a voltage drop across them (depending upon color) from 6 - 12 Volts. since there is a stack of three of them.  Therefore the residual voltage with low or zero current draw will be on the same size/magnitude.  This means that the voltage across the LED's won't collapse quickly below this voltage when power is removed.

The shunt resistor in front of the diode is a bleed resistor, it is meant to bleed off charge from the de-rippling capacitors in the event of a power down.  This prevent the capacitors from providing a voltage (back feed) to the +12V input when powered down.

These voltages are not dangerous to humans, it's more of a circuit protection scheme.

Comment: Hi, I do believe that it is related to low band pass filter. Kindly suggest.

Comment: @NehaSahni draw out a LFP and then come back and see if you still think that.

Comment: Yes you are right it is not Low band pass filter. Is it related to Filtration for transient controlling. ( EMI / EMC) ?